# Jasmine: How to use it to test an application built with webpack?

Tags: webpack, jasmine

I looked at the [code example](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases) for Jasmine

Now, I decided to build the two source javascript files named src/Player.js and src/Song.js to a bundle file, and instead of the lines:

```
<script src="src/Player.js"></script>
<script src="src/Song.js"></script>
```

put the line: 
  
in SpecRunner.html.

Theoretically,bundle.js should include the same code as Player.js and Song.js. And yet, when I open SpecRunner.html, I still get the error:

> ReferenceError: Player is not defined

It probably means that Jasmine have difficulties reading bundle.js file. I want to ask how to use Jasmine to test a bundled js file?

Here is the code of the project: https://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/project/editor/XvEmQM#

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works good:
http://www.thinksincode.com/2016/07/07/karma-jasmine-webpack.html?fref=gc&dti=415197258523958

Karma is needed, but it's not so complicated. 
You can also see here a good boilerplate:
https://bitbucket.org/knee-cola/webpack-karma/